# Postgres full text search: Word positioning is results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, string-matching, tsvector

I am trying to figure out how to create TsQuery where when I query "Executive Sales"
I get only results that have "Executive Sales" as the **first and second word**.
For example

- Executive Sales Manager
- Executive Sales Representative
  etc.

I have tried with Executive <-> Sales:*
but this gives me results like:

- Account Executive Sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTS is the wrong tool for that job.

```
col1 LIKE 'Executive Sales%'
```